# run a query through oozie (no script)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, oozie

I am trying to submit non preformed queries of adhoc nature via oozie.
From oozie hive action extension documentation http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/DG_HiveActionExtension.html, I can have following in my workflow xml file:-

```
        <script>someScriptWithQuery.q</script>
        <param>TABLE=foo</param>
```

Here someScriptWithQuery.q can contain a hive query with parametrized tablename and needs to reside on hdfs system.

What I am trying to understand is - if I have a case wherein

(1) it is not possible to pre-form a query but it has to built on an adhoc basis(basically means I cannot use "script" tag in above workflow xml) and

(2) it is not feasible to have a script on hdfs system (and hence I cannot parametrize entire query) -

In this scenario- how do I submit that query through oozie? My question is related to somewhat similar post here [Scheduling an ad-hoc query with Hive/Hadoop using Oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275414/scheduling-an-ad-hoc-query-with-hive-hadoop-using-oozie).

Are there any other possible ways to achieve this? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your two questions:

1) Yes you can, just add another  node like:

```
<script>someScriptWithQuery.q</script>
<param>TABLE=foo</param>
<file>someTransformScript</file?
```

and then use that script inside the query with USING 'someTransformScript'

2) it is always feasible if your hadoop server support that script, e.g. your nodes have all the required dependencies and so on

Hope this helps